# Boats and Streams:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boat takes 90 Minutes less to travel 36 Miles downstream than to travel the same distance upstream.If the speed of the boat in still water is 10mph , the speed of the stream is :

I have tried:

let distance be 36 ,td be time taken for downstream and tu be time taken for upstream

speed = distance/time

36/td - 36/tu = 90

36(1/td - 1/tu)= 90

**can you guide me for the answer I dont have an idea about doing the sum**

Comment: The effectve speed of the boat downstream is 10 mph PLUS the stream speed, and the effective speed upstream is 10 mph MINUS the stream speed. The difference of those two speeds is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of the stream is $x$, then $10+x, 10-x $ are the speeds of the boat going down and upstream respectively. Then the down and upstream times are $\dfrac{36}{10+x}, \dfrac{36}{10-x}$. So: $\dfrac{36}{10+x} + 1.5 = \dfrac{36}{10-x}$. Can you proceed to find $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that - Speed of boat in downstream = speed of boat in still water + Stream speed.

Similarly,

Speed of boat in upstream = Speed of boat in still water - Stream speed.

Let Stream speed = x

Downstream speed = 10 + x

Upstream speed = 10 - x

Then,

$\frac{36}{10 - x} - \frac{36}{10 + x} = \frac{90}{60}$

$36\left(\frac{10 + x - 10 + x}{(10 - x)(10 + x)}\right) = \frac{3}{2}$

$12\left(\frac{2x}{(100 - x^2)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$

Cross multiply terms,

$48x = 100 - x^2$

$x^2 + 48x - 100 = 0$

$x^2 + 50x - 2x - 100 = 0$

$x(x + 50) - 2(x + 50) = 0$

$(x - 2)(x + 50) = 0$

x = 2, -50

Speed can't be negative in this case. So x = 2 is answer.

Comment: I want Your personal chat ,please

Comment: I have another question in similar topic guide me please

Comment: Discussion room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics can you come here

Comment: Hi@Kanwalijit singh, can you please come to the chat